# Microk8s can't run sample Ingress configuration

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress, microk8s

I am creating a cluster using microk8S platform. I have enabled metallb and ingress addons in order to create a load balancing mechanism. I found sample nginx deployment/build and I am trying to run it on my machine.
My config.yaml file looks as follows:

```
#Deployment
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: nginx-deployment
  labels:
    app: nginx
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: nginx
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: nginx
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: nginx
          image: nginx:1.14.2
          ports:
            - containerPort: 80
#Service
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: nginx-service
spec:
  selector:
    app: nginx
  ports:
    - protocol: TCP
      port: 80
      targetPort: 80
#Ingress resource
---
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: nginx-ingress
  annotations:
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/use-forwarded-headers: "true"
spec:
  ingressClassName: public
  rules:
    - host: "api.mysite.net"
      http:
        paths:
          - path: /
            pathType: Prefix
            backend:
              service:
                name: nginx-service
                port:
                  number: 80
#LoadBalancer
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: ingresslb
  namespace: ingress
spec:
  selector:
    name: nginx-ingress
  type: LoadBalancer
  ports:
    - name: http
      protocol: TCP
      port: 80
      targetPort: 80
    - name: https
      protocol: TCP
      port: 443
      targetPort: 443
```

After running the configuration, all services get created:
[All Resources](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HiEls.png)

First, I test nginx-service from inside the cluster. The service works fine, as shown in the picture:
[Testing service](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2QECQ.png)

**However, when I visit external ip address of ingress load balancer I just get empty page**:
[Ingress doesn't route requests to service](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M1iX2.png)

I have configured /etc/hosts file to include my hostname:
[Hosts are updated](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZkwlC.png)

I don't know why my Ingress fails. Any help would be apriciated.

I have checked and compared my ingress resource configuration to sample configuration I found in official documentation but Ingress routing still doesn't work.